# Show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln x[\ln(\ln x)]^{\frac23}}$ is decreasing for all $x > 3$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, logarithms, slope

Show that $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln x[\ln(\ln x)]^{\frac23}}$$ is decreasing $\forall x > 3$.

How can I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. For $x>e$, the denominator is the product of increasing and positive functions.

Comment: And if you take inverse of it that means it is decreasing?

Comment: @Mathrix Yes, you are correct!